# How to make communication between UWP Client and Java Server using WebSocket?

Tags: java, c#, websocket, uwp

I need to send text,primitive data types and object between a UWP client and JAVA server using WebSocket, however I don't know how to code.

I don't understand if there is any difference between these two languages that make coding thing really hard? (I've searched for online tutorials but still couldn't make my code works).

**Provider.java** :

```
public class Provider{
    ServerSocket providerSocket;
    Socket connection = null;
    OutputStream out;
    InputStream in;
    String message;
    MesageModel model;
    Provider(){}
    void run()
    {
        try{
            providerSocket = new ServerSocket(9999, 10);
            //2. Wait for connection
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
            connection = providerSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("New connection accepted "+":" + connection.getPort());
            in = connection.getInputStream();
            out = connection.getOutputStream();
            if(out == null)
            {
                System.out.println("Out Status : Null");
            }else
            {
                System.out.println("Out Status : Not Null");
                sendMessage("Hello Client");
            }
            if(in == null)
            {
                System.out.println("In Status : Null");
            }else
            {
                receiveConnection();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            //4: Closing connection
            try{
                if(in != null){
                    System.out.println("Close In");
                in.close();
                }
                if(out != null){
                    System.out.println("Close Out");
                     out.close();
                }
                System.out.println("Close Socket");
                 providerSocket.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    void receiveConnection() throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder outsb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        System.out.println("In Status : Not Null");
        System.out.println("In Status : Go To While to Read Line");
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            outsb.append(line);
            System.out.println(outsb.toString()); 
        }
        System.out.println(outsb.toString());   
        reader.close();
        System.out.println("Closed Reader");
    }
    void sendMessage(String msg)
    {
        byte[] byteS = msg.getBytes();
        try{
            out.write(byteS);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("To Server >" + msg);
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Provider server = new Provider();
        while(true){
            server.run();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace WebsocketTest
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            createSocket();
        }
        public async void createSocket()
        {
            MessageWebSocket webSock = new MessageWebSocket();
            webSock.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Binary;
            webSock.MessageReceived += webSock_MsgReceived;
            webSock.Closed += webSock_Closed;
            Uri serverUri = new Uri("ws://localhost:9999");
            try
            {
                await webSock.ConnectAsync(serverUri);
                tbConnect.Text = "Connected";
                webSock_SendMessage( webSock, "Hello");
                tbError.Text = "Sent Greeting";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tbError.Text = ex.Message + " / " + ex.HResult + " / " + ex.Data;
            }
        }

        private async Task webSock_SendMessage(MessageWebSocket webSock, string m)
        {
            BinaryWriter messageWriter = new BinaryWriter((Stream)webSock.OutputStream);
            messageWriter.Write(m);
        }

        private void webSock_Closed(IWebSocket sender, WebSocketClosedEventArgs args)
        {

        }

        private void webSock_MsgReceived(MessageWebSocket sender, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
        {   
            DataReader messageReader = args.GetDataReader();
            messageReader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
            string messageString = messageReader.ReadString(messageReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
            tbReceived.Text = messageString;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently these code don't work at all,  ... I can't send, can't read ... at both side.

**My Questions:**

How to Send and Read Messages from my UWP client?

How to Send and Read Messages from my JAVA server?

Please I need something helpful ... a code sample.

Comment: removed tutorial and resources recommendations

Comment: This document: [WebSockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/websockets) and the [WebSocket sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebSocket) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your Java code creates a plain TCP/IP socket, not a [websocket][1], which is a higher level protocol on top of TCP/IP.

If you want websockets you need to either implement websockets for yourself (don't do that if you are not very experienced at network programming) or use a Java library that provides websocket server functionality. Jetty, Netty or J2EE servers might be candidates for that.